# Initially hidden radioButton dont be visible on event

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener, jradiobutton

I'm trying to make a component visible when i clicked on a radio button. 
RadioButton initialized hidden in initComponents method.

I have put a mouseClickListener on radio button. It doesnt work if I initialize radioButton hidden. Works if i initialize it visible (default):

[image: look at this]

I have also tried to initialize at pre-post init.

These are myListeners and txtMaas is initialized hidden:

```
private void rbOgretmenMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    txtMaas.setVisible(true);
}                                       

private void rbOgrenciMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    txtMaas.setVisible(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use an ItemListener on your JRadioButton, not a MouseListener.
2. After setting a component visible or invisible, be sure to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the parent container, usually a JPanel, that holds the component whose visibility you've changed. The revalidate allows the container's layout manager to re-layout its components and the repaint allows the Graphics object to re-paint the container and all its components.
3. For more detailed help, consider creating and posting a [minimal example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (please check out the link).

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class RadioFun extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 300;
    private static final int PREF_H = 150;
    private JRadioButton rbOgret = new JRadioButton("Ogret");
    private JTextField txtMaas = new JTextField(10);

    public RadioFun() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
        add(rbOgret);
        add(txtMaas);

        txtMaas.setVisible(false);

        rbOgret.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                rbOgretItemStateChanged(e);
            }
        });
    }    

    // to make the GUI large enough
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private void rbOgretItemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        boolean visible = e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED;
        txtMaas.setVisible(visible);

        // call repaint and revalidate on the holding JPanel:
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }

    // the two methods below are to create the GUI on the Swing event thread
    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("RadioFun");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new RadioFun());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```